# "This item is temporarily unavailable" When Installing Yosemite

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, install

I have erased my HD and tried to install OS Yosemite on MacBook Pro mid 2009. But keep getting this message "This item is temporarily unavailable." I've tried many proposed solutions but none seem to work. Any one experienced a similar problem?

Comment: Install the original OS from DVD, then you'll be able to access the store to download Yosemite, assuming it's in your purchase list.  Unless it is in your purchase history, it will always be unavailable.

Comment: I don't have DVD of the original OS and my DVD driver didn't work ..

Comment: Then it's a trip to the Apple Store, I think. I doubt you'll get an 09 Mac to boot from USB

Comment: Well.. We don't have Apple Store here in Kuwait :), I hope I will find some solution

Comment: Perhaps there is a apple premium reseller instead of an apple store?

Comment: use command+option+r

Comment: @Timmerz It's working.

Answer (score 4):

Let me preface this: it's possible that this solution doesn't work entirely, and that you'll need a version of the installer that has a full copy of OS X (instead of downloading it from the internet on the fly.)

With that said, [here's the issue](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6455578?tstart=0). Your Apple ID (and therefore purchases) are not associated with the computer you're trying to install to since it's a clean install. Therefore, it doesn't know you've "purchased" Yosemite previously, and since it's no longer on the app store, isn't giving you access. What you need to do is reassociate your Apple ID with that computer. The recommended solution is to log into icloud.com.

Alternatively (or if that doesn't work), you can download it from another computer with a working version of OS X and then execute the installer from there (or create a bootable installer from there.)

Small side question: why not install El Cap?

Comment: I've tried the iCloud login first, didn't work...I've created a bootable disk on external drive which is available for OS lion only .. Didn't wok. Why not El Cap? Because when trying to install from the recovery screen, it goes to installing Yosemite by default and cannot change that

Comment: @Yousef You can create bootable volumes/installers for any version of OSX. Are you using Internet Recovery? That would explain why it's defaulting to Yosemite, as Internet Recovery uses the version of OS X that came with your Mac.

Answer (score 3):

Finally the problem solved... I have noticed there is no Yosemite update purchased in my App Store account! So looked in the accounts of my family members and found one in my son's account. I used his account in the installation screen and it worked.
Thanks all who tried to help :)

Comment: how were you able to login to your app store?

Answer (score 0):

Checked that you're Apple Id is connected to the correct App Store region.

The easiest way is, in App Store, select go Store > View My Account ...

A check will be made if the App Store region will be checked, and, if they're out of sync, at this point, the correct region for your Apple Id will be selected.

After this point, you should be able to install apps and updates from the App Store.